# textarea height won't back to normal after resizing/submitting form

Tags: jquery, css, textarea, jtextfield, jtextarea

I'm having problem with autosize textarea plugin by jquery, I use jquery to insert data to mysql, so the page doesn't need to refresh while passing the strings.

when texting over one line, the plugin work properly by resizing height and follow the string contents, but after I submited it, the textarea field won't go back to the normal height. it need to be refreshed to back to normal height. 
is there any simple code I could use to fix it?

here is my jquery code to pass the value:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("submit.php",{val1:val1,receiver1:receiver1},
           function(output){
            $("#posting").append(output);
    });

});
```

here is the jquery plugin I use :

```
/*!
    Autosize v1.17.2 - 2013-07-30
    Automatically adjust textarea height based on user input.
    (c) 2013 Jack Moore - http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize
    license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*/
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals: jQuery or jQuery-like library, such as Zepto
        factory(window.jQuery || window.$);
    }
}(function ($) {
    var
    defaults = {
        className: 'autosizejs',
        append: '',
        callback: false,
        resizeDelay: 10
    },

    // border:0 is unnecessary, but avoids a bug in FireFox on OSX
    copy = '<textarea tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-999px; left:0; right:auto; bottom:auto; border:0; -moz-box-sizing:content-box; -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; box-sizing:content-box; word-wrap:break-word; height:0 !important; min-height:0 !important; overflow:hidden; transition:none; -webkit-transition:none; -moz-transition:none;"/>',

    // line-height is conditionally included because IE7/IE8/old Opera do not return the correct value.
    typographyStyles = [
        'fontFamily',
        'fontSize',
        'fontWeight',
        'fontStyle',
        'letterSpacing',
        'textTransform',
        'wordSpacing',
        'textIndent'
    ],

    // to keep track which textarea is being mirrored when adjust() is called.
    mirrored,

    // the mirror element, which is used to calculate what size the mirrored element should be.
    mirror = $(copy).data('autosize', true)[0];

    // test that line-height can be accurately copied.
    mirror.style.lineHeight = '99px';
    if ($(mirror).css('lineHeight') === '99px') {
        typographyStyles.push('lineHeight');
    }
    mirror.style.lineHeight = '';

    $.fn.autosize = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});

        if (mirror.parentNode !== document.body) {
            $(document.body).append(mirror);
        }

        return this.each(function () {
            var
            ta = this,
            $ta = $(ta),
            maxHeight,
            minHeight,
            boxOffset = 0,
            callback = $.isFunction(options.callback),
            originalStyles = {
                height: ta.style.height,
                overflow: ta.style.overflow,
                overflowY: ta.style.overflowY,
                wordWrap: ta.style.wordWrap,
                resize: ta.style.resize
            },
            timeout,
            width = $ta.width();

            if ($ta.data('autosize')) {
                // exit if autosize has already been applied, or if the textarea is the mirror element.
                return;
            }
            $ta.data('autosize', true);

            if ($ta.css('box-sizing') === 'border-box' || $ta.css('-moz-box-sizing') === 'border-box' || $ta.css('-webkit-box-sizing') === 'border-box'){
                boxOffset = $ta.outerHeight() - $ta.height();
            }

            // IE8 and lower return 'auto', which parses to NaN, if no min-height is set.
            minHeight = Math.max(parseInt($ta.css('minHeight'), 10) - boxOffset || 0, $ta.height());

            $ta.css({
                overflow: 'hidden',
                overflowY: 'hidden',
                wordWrap: 'break-word', // horizontal overflow is hidden, so break-word is necessary for handling words longer than the textarea width
                resize: ($ta.css('resize') === 'none' || $ta.css('resize') === 'vertical') ? 'none' : 'horizontal'
            });

            function initMirror() {
                var styles = {}, ignore;

                mirrored = ta;
                mirror.className = options.className;
                maxHeight = parseInt($ta.css('maxHeight'), 10);

                // mirror is a duplicate textarea located off-screen that
                // is automatically updated to contain the same text as the
                // original textarea.  mirror always has a height of 0.
                // This gives a cross-browser supported way getting the actual
                // height of the text, through the scrollTop property.
                $.each(typographyStyles, function(i,val){
                    styles[val] = $ta.css(val);
                });
                $(mirror).css(styles);

                // The textarea overflow is probably now hidden, but Chrome doesn't reflow the text to account for the
                // new space made available by removing the scrollbars. This workaround causes Chrome to reflow the text.
                if ('oninput' in ta) {
                    var width = ta.style.width;
                    ta.style.width = '0px';
                    ignore = ta.offsetWidth; // This value isn't used, but getting it triggers the necessary reflow
                    ta.style.width = width;
                }
            }

            // Using mainly bare JS in this function because it is going
            // to fire very often while typing, and needs to very efficient.
            function adjust() {
                var height, original, width, style;

                if (mirrored !== ta) {
                    initMirror();
                }

                mirror.value = ta.value + options.append;
                mirror.style.overflowY = ta.style.overflowY;
                original = parseInt(ta.style.height,10);

                // window.getComputedStyle, getBoundingClientRect returning a width are unsupported in IE8 and lower.
                // The mirror width must exactly match the textarea width, so using getBoundingClientRect because it doesn't round the sub-pixel value.
                if ('getComputedStyle' in window) {
                    style = window.getComputedStyle(ta);
                    width = ta.getBoundingClientRect().width;

                    $.each(['paddingLeft', 'paddingRight', 'borderLeftWidth', 'borderRightWidth'], function(i,val){
                        width -= parseInt(style[val],10);
                    });

                    mirror.style.width = width + 'px';
                }
                else {
                    mirror.style.width = Math.max($ta.width(), 0) + 'px';
                }

                // Needed for IE8 and lower to reliably return the correct scrollTop
                mirror.scrollTop = 0;

                mirror.scrollTop = 9e4;

                // Using scrollTop rather than scrollHeight because scrollHeight is non-standard and includes padding.
                height = mirror.scrollTop;

                if (maxHeight && height > maxHeight) {
                    ta.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
                    height = maxHeight;
                } else {
                    ta.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
                    if (height < minHeight) {
                        height = minHeight;
                    }
                }

                height += boxOffset;

                if (original !== height) {
                    ta.style.height = height + 'px';
                    if (callback) {
                        options.callback.call(ta,ta);
                    }
                }
            }

            function resize () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    if ($ta.width() !== width) {
                        adjust();
                    }
                }, parseInt(options.resizeDelay,10));
            }

            if ('onpropertychange' in ta) {
                if ('oninput' in ta) {
                    // Detects IE9.  IE9 does not fire onpropertychange or oninput for deletions,
                    // so binding to onkeyup to catch most of those occasions.  There is no way that I
                    // know of to detect something like 'cut' in IE9.
                    $ta.on('input.autosize keyup.autosize', adjust);
                } else {
                    // IE7 / IE8
                    $ta.on('propertychange.autosize', function(){
                        if(event.propertyName === 'value'){
                            adjust();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                // Modern Browsers
                $ta.on('input.autosize', adjust);
            }

            // Set options.resizeDelay to false if using fixed-width textarea elements.
            // Uses a timeout and width check to reduce the amount of times adjust needs to be called after window resize.

            if (options.resizeDelay !== false) {
                $(window).on('resize.autosize', resize);
            }

            // Event for manual triggering if needed.
            // Should only be needed when the value of the textarea is changed through JavaScript rather than user input.
            $ta.on('autosize.resize', adjust);

            // Event for manual triggering that also forces the styles to update as well.
            // Should only be needed if one of typography styles of the textarea change, and the textarea is already the target of the adjust method.
            $ta.on('autosize.resizeIncludeStyle', function() {
                mirrored = null;
                adjust();
            });

            $ta.on('autosize.destroy', function(){
                mirrored = null;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                $(window).off('resize', resize);
                $ta
                    .off('autosize')
                    .off('.autosize')
                    .css(originalStyles)
                    .removeData('autosize');
            });

            // Call adjust in case the textarea already contains text.
            adjust();
        });
    };
}));
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

you can save the original height before submit and then restore it after you submitted your form?

```
var OriginalHeight = $("#text-area").height();
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("submit.php",{val1:val1,receiver1:receiver1},
           function(output){
            $("#posting").append(output);
    });
    $("#text-area").height(OriginalHeight);
});
```

replace #text-area with your text-area correct id.

Edit:
Works like a charm
http://jsfiddle.net/Quvku/

Make sure you are including jQuery before this script, if you are not sure wrap the script  in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//place script here
});
```